# Dual of an elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, duality-theorems

Since an elliptic curve given by the homogenized polynomial $$y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3$$ is a plane projective curve, we can get its dual.

From this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve), eliminating $p$, $q$, $r$, and $λ$ from the following equations, $$X-\lambda \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p,q,r) = X- \lambda (-3p^2-ar^2) =0\tag{1}$$ $$Y-\lambda \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p,q,r) = Y- \lambda (2qr) =0\tag{2}$$ $$Z-\lambda \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p,q,r) = Z- \lambda (q^2-2apr-3br^2) =0\tag{3}$$ $$Xp+Yq+Zr=0\tag{4}$$ yields the equation of the dual curve. However, no matter how I try to solve it, I always fail to eliminate all those variables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll warn you in advance that this is not going to be pretty.

The $\lambda$ obviously doesn't matter because we are working with projective coordinates $X:Y:Z$.  So we might as well put $\lambda=1$.  The final equation just asserts $p:q:r$ is on the original curve $q^2r-p^3-apr^2-br^3=0$ when you substitute in $X,Y,Z$, but let's keep it in the original form $Xp+Yq+Zr=0$.

First step is to use $Xp+Yq+Zr=0$ to eliminate one of $p,q,r$.  So let's try eliminating $p$, giving
\begin{align*}
X^3+3(qY+rZ)^2+ar^2X^2&=0\\
Y-2qr&=0\\
ZX-q^2X-2ar(qY+rZ)+3br^2X&=0
\end{align*}
Next, eliminate $q$ using $Y=2qr$,
\begin{align*}
0&=r^2X^3+3(Y^2/2+r^2Z)^2+ar^4X^2\\
&=r^4(aX^2+3Z^2)+r^2(X^3+3Y^2Z)+\frac34Y^4
\\
0&=r^2ZX-\frac14XY^2-ar^2(Y^2+2r^2Z)+3br^4X\\
&=r^4(3bX-2aZ)+r^2(ZX-aY^2)-\frac14XY^2
\end{align*}
Finally, eliminate $r^2$:
\begin{align*}
0&=\operatorname{Res}_{r^2}(r^4(aX^2+3Z^2)+r^2(X^3+3Y^2Z)+\frac34Y^4,r^4(3bX-2aZ)+r^2(ZX-aY^2)-\frac14XY^2)\\
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}
aX^2+3Z^2&X^3+3Y^2Z&\frac34Y^4\\
&aX^2+3Z^2&X^3+3Y^2Z&\frac34Y^4\\
3bX-2aZ&ZX-aY^2&-\frac14XY^2\\
&3bX-2aZ&ZX-aY^2&-\frac14XY^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
giving
$$
\frac3{16} X^2 Y^2 (4 a^3 Y^6 - a^2 X^4 Y^2 - 24 a^2 X Y^4 Z + 18 a b X^2 Y^4 + 4 a X^5 Z + 30 a X^2 Y^2 Z^2 + 27 b^2 Y^6 - 4 b X^6 - 36 b X^3 Y^2 Z - 54 b Y^4 Z^2 + 4 X^3 Z^3 + 27 Y^2 Z^4)=0
$$
The factor $X^2Y^2$ was introduced by our desire to keep everything as polynomial when eliminating $p,q$ (we have multiplied equation by $X^2$, $r^2$), and not actually part of the dual curve.  So the end result is
$$
4 a^3 Y^6 - a^2 X^4 Y^2 - 24 a^2 X Y^4 Z + 18 a b X^2 Y^4 + 4 a X^5 Z + 30 a X^2 Y^2 Z^2 + 27 b^2 Y^6 - 4 b X^6 - 36 b X^3 Y^2 Z - 54 b Y^4 Z^2 + 4 X^3 Z^3 + 27 Y^2 Z^4 = 0.
$$

Comment: It is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) (wiki has the matrix transposed for some silly reason).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I posted another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286645/dual-curve-of-elliptic-curve) regarding this and I hope you can help me out!